# Snowflake h/w failure during time travel

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What happens if h/w failure happens  in time travel period ??
My assumption is that if a h/w failure happens during time travel we can on own restore the database while h/w failure during the fail-safe time can be handled only by SF

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.

Time travel can be used for restoring the objects from your end, while the object is within the defined Data retention time set.

Fail-safe ensures historical data is protected in the event of a system failure and the objects can be restored through Snowflake support.

Comment: Fail safe time is after time travel ??

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake is a deployment on your CSP of choice, either AWS, Azure or GCP. The micropartitions live in a Snowflake managed bucket.
That means Snowflake uses the CSP's native support for Multi-AZ protection of data. The likelyhood of any failure is very unlikely.